# Blocks submitted to a GCD serial queue causes memory to grow indefinitely

Tags: ios, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have a piece of code that on a timer callback dispatches blocks to a serial queue. For testing the block is empty meaning it doesn't have any code in it. Nevertheless, I'm seeing the memory allocation of my app increasing. Is it because gcd is not deallocating fast enough the submitted blocks? Or is it something to do with the number of threads that gcd is spawning (like indicated by [Memory usage for global GCD queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132333/memory-usage-for-global-gcd-queue)) ? 
I also tried changing the serial queue with a concurrent queue and does solve the memory growth but I was wondering if anyone has a good explanation and recommendation on how to solve the problem other than using a concurrent queue.

**UPDATE**

Here is the sample code I'm using to debug this problem:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   self.httpRequestOperationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
   self.httpRequestOperationManager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

   self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("my_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

   NSString *urlString = @"<URL>";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

   self.request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:5];

   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f
                                    target:self
                                  selector:@selector(fetch)
                                  userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:YES];

  return YES;
}

- (void)fetch
{
     AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [self.httpRequestOperationManager
                                     HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:self.request
                              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                  dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
                                      NSLog(@"DISPATCHING ASYNC CAUSES MEMORY TO GROWTH");
                                  });
                              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                              }];

    [self.httpRequestOperationManager.operationQueue addOperation:op];

}
```

**NOTES**

1. The problem doesn't occur if self.queue is the main queue. Is it because blocks dispatched on the main queue are drained a lot faster??
2. The problem doesn't occur if self.queue is a concurrent queue (dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0))
3. My problem is similar to [Calling AFNetworking in NSTimer causes serious memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011278/calling-afnetworking-in-nstimer-causes-serious-memory-leak) and I tried what is recommended there but didn't help.
4. I'm using iOS9.0 with AF v2.6.1

The image below shows the memory growth after 12 minutes..and the memory allocation continues to growth!

[image: Sample app memory report after 12 minutes]

Comment: Some code would be useful here. There's a good chance that you've got retain cycles by capturing strong references - but it's hard to know with out seeing the code.

Comment: What are the blocks you are submitting?  The memory might be accumulating in an autoreleasepool.  If you use a lot of memory in your block, you can submit it with its own @autoreleasepool {} block.  However, we can't really help you without more context.

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply. I added some sample code (see updates). I think it's related to using AFNetworking and dispatching asynchronously on a serial queue for reason that I'm not sure. Hope some one can shade some light!